# Kivy language code of my Vehicle Details app

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

So I've written my first android app in kivy.

This app takes a Vehicle License Number as input from the user and submits it to a sites and shows the results from the site.

The complete Source Code of the app is at https://github.com/Logmytech/Andhra-pradesh-vehicle-lookup

Here is the Kivy language code:

```
<RootWidget>:

#This is the root widget's kv definition

    search_input: ap
    roosvelt:roosvelt
    Screen:

        name: 'Screen 1'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            TextInput:
                id: ap
                hint_text: 'Enter the license plate number here'
                size_hint: (1,0.1)
                muliline: False

            Button:
                text: 'Search number'
                on_press:root.postbug()
                size_hint: (1,0.1)

            Label:
                text: "Works for AP numbers only"
                id:roosvelt
```

Here is some Python code from the app that is related:

`class RootWidget(ScreenManager):`

The RootWidget which contains all the logic of the app inherits from `ScreenManager`.

`self.roosvelt.text= ".........."`

So roosvelt is a text label which I use to show data to the user.

Here is a screenshot of the app in action.

[image: Andhra Pardesh Vehicle Lookup]